# OneDrive for Business ~ 1GB download for installation

Tags: installation, onedrive-for-business, packaging, networking, offline-sync

Anyone there having issues with the OneDrive for Business installation requiring 1 GB download? For low-bandwidth locations, having OD4B rolled out could be quite a challenge (either for online / LAN installation, I'm aware of the possibility to use the Office Deployment Tool with a network file share).

Is there a way to package it to a smaller size?

Answer (score 0):

that's the only two options, live installation vs Offline using the Office deployment tool.

Basically when you download the package, it’s the entire Office 2013 install with the OneDrive for Business components enabled.

But when you run it and connect internet then size is really small because it will only download the component which required for OneDrive business only. in this case size will be reduced.

Comment: _really small_ means about 500 MB (tested yesterday). The same size stands for the network share installation.

Comment: our Office deployment package is about 898MB. so if you compare it 500 is lot less....But i agree with you on slow connection it cause big problem...offline will be only option